# How to prevent find traversing certain directories, but still list them?

Tags: find

I have the following folder structure:

```
example/
├── bar/
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   ├── 4
│   ├── 5.txt
│   ├── bar.mylib/
│   │   ├── 1
│   │   ├── 2
│   │   ├── 3
│   │   ├── 4
│   │   ├── 5
│   │   ├── 6
│   │   └── foo/
│   │       ├── 1
│   │       ├── 3
│   │       └── 5
│   └── foo.mylib
└── foo/
    ├── 1
    ├── 3
    ├── 5
    └── node_modules/
        ├── 1
        ├── 2
        ├── 3
        ├── 4
        └── 5

5 directories, 23 files
```

I want to build a `find` command that would list all the files and directories, but excluding specific directory name patterns, without entering in those directories at all, but still include the directory names in the output.

The following output is expected:

```
example/
example/foo/
example/foo/3
example/foo/5
example/foo/1
example/foo/node_modules/
example/bar/
example/bar/5.txt
example/bar/3
example/bar/4
example/bar/1
example/bar/bar.mylib/
example/bar/foo.mylib
example/bar/2
```

I tried the following:

```
find . -type f ! -path '*/*.mylib/*' ! -path '*/node_modules/*'
```

This kind of works, *but* it seems to enter in those directories that are ignored. Also, it is not listing the ignored directories (namely `example/foo/node_modules/` and `example/bar/bar.mylib/`).

I intentionally have two `.mylib` paths: one is directory and the other is a file. I want to list both, but ignore the content of the directory.

How can we do this with `find`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strategy is to prune all directories matching your `node_modules` or `*.mylib` (prune means to not descend into them) and print all other files.

```
find . -print \( -type d \( -name 'node_modules' -o -name '*.mylib' \) -prune \)
```

Consult [Find's specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) or the manual if any of the above options is foreign to you.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. I would like to add the trailing `/` after the directory paths if it is easy.

Comment: @IonicăBizău You are welcome. Yeah, that doesn't work because the found directories do not get the final `/`. GNU Find even warns me that `find: warning: -path node_modules/ will not match anything because it ends with /.`